# How to solve "Could not determine recommended JdbcType" error in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a model class Employee that inherits from another class Person. The classes are shown below;

Employee:

```
import java.util.Date;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class Employee extends Person{
 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="employeetypeid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private EmployeeType employeeType;
 private Integer employeetypeid;
 private String photo;
 private String username;

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="jobtitleid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
 private JobTitle jobTitle;
 private Integer jobtitleid;

 @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
 private Date hireDate;
}
```

Person

```
import java.util.Date;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String othername;
    @Formula(value = " concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) ")
    private String fullName;
    private String title;
    private String initials;
    private String socialSecurityNumber;
    private String gender;
    private String maritalStatus;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="countryid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private Country country;
    private Integer countryid;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="stateid", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private State state;
    private Integer stateid;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    private String city;
    private String address;
    private String phone;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private String photo;
}
```

EmployeeType class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;

@Entity
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
public class EmployeeType extends CommonObject{
}
```

CommonObject class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIdentityInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.ObjectIdGenerators;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator= ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class)
public class CommonObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer Id;
    private String description;
    private String details;

    public CommonObject(Integer id, String description, String details) {
        Id = id;
        this.description = description;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public CommonObject() {
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CommonObject{" +
                "Id=" + Id +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", details='" + details + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

See my application.properties below;

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fleetappdb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
server.error.include-message=alwaysspring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fleetappdb?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ids05!!
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
server.error.include-message=always
```

On running the application, I get the error below;

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1158) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at com.scriptx.fleet.FleetappApplication.main(FleetappApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.JdbcTypeRecommendationException: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `com.scriptx.fleet.models.Employee`
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.spi.UnknownBasicJavaType.getRecommendedJdbcType(UnknownBasicJavaType.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.internal.InferredBasicValueResolver.from(InferredBasicValueResolver.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.buildResolution(BasicValue.java:480) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.BasicValue.resolve(BasicValue.java:300) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.lambda$processValueResolvers$4(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1855) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1765) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.removeIf(ArrayList.java:1743) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processValueResolvers(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1854) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1840) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:331) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.9.Final.jar:6.2.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
```

My pom.xml is below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.scriptx.fleet</groupId>
    <artifactId>fleetapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>fleetapp</name>
    <description>Fleet Management Application</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What could I be doing wrong?

I expected the application to run and be accessible on the browser, but am getting the error;

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Could not determine recommended JdbcType for
> `com.scriptx.fleet.models.Employee`

Comment: please share class `EmployeeType`

Comment: Two additional classes (EmployeeType and CommonObject ) have been added. @Jens

Comment: More details provided, two additional classes added, @Jens please check

Comment: what else do you have that might reference Employee? Are you sure that what you've shown in the only `com.scriptx.fleet.models.Employee` class in there? From my understanding of how this might occur, something picked up in the persistence unit from Spring scanning packages is referencing `com.scriptx.fleet.models.Employee` and the instance of that class that it finds isn't marked as an entity, or the mapping itself referencing it is Basic